# Silverlight not initializing controls

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to add some values in several controls in my silverlight page (textboxes, datepickers...) but it seems like some of them are never initialize (until user sets any value manually).

I've tried it by been suscribed to the "Loaded" event in the page's code behind but it doesn't work... (I thought it was because of the order it was being initialized).

I've read that this is one of silverlight limitations but maybe there is any workaround...

Any idea?? Thanks in advance.

Some code to illustrate it, first the xaml controls:

```
<sdk:Label Target="{Binding ElementName=txtNumeroColegiado}" Content="Nº Colegiado" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<TextBox Margin="5,0" Name="txtNumeroColegiado" TabIndex="27" Text="{Binding Medico.colegiado, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" />

<sdk:Label Target="{Binding ElementName=txtNombreComercial}" Content="Nombre Comercial" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" />
<TextBox Margin="5,0" Name="txtNombreComercial" TabIndex="27" Text="{Binding Medico.nombrecomercial, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3" />
```

And this is my conde behind:

```
public DatosMedico()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(DatosMedico_Loaded);
}

void DatosMedico_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     this.txtNombreComercial.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
     this.txtNumeroColegiado.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```

When it tries to run "updateSource", these textboxes are null (but they are working perfectly in the page...). Apparently they are initialized when user inputs some text...

Comment: This isn't making much sense.  Where to set the `DataContext`?  Why would you force an  `UpdateSource` in the way you are?  No data in the boxes would have changed at that point, remove that code.

Comment: The DataContext is set in the parent page (this is a control on fact) and it's inherited perfectly. I make that UpdateSource to force a "validation" before letting the user edit the form (I've tried it through messages with a mediator and the controls are null yet too)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solutioned by deleting a "ContentPresenter" that had many controls inside.

Answer (score 0):

At guess, the `DataContext` is either not being set or not set to the object you are expecting it to be set to.  Check the output window in VS when debugging, do you see any complaints about binding?

Comment: The DataContext is set in the parent page (this is a control on fact) and it's inherited perfectly. I make that UpdateSource to force a "validation" before letting the user edit the form (I've tried it through messages with a mediator and the controls are null yet too)...